# Генерация случайных чисел в Python по заданной функции распределения и мат ожиданию?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Как в питоне сгенерировать N случайных чисел, если нам известна функция распределения и мат ожидание? 
Что использовать?
может SciPy или numpy?

Comment: о какой функции распределения идет речь? она заранее известна?